# How can I show a large amount of text in a jQuery UI dialog box instead of an alert box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following:

```
alert(ajaxContext.responseText);
```

This shows quite a large amount of information and the alert box truncates the error text so I cannot see the full message. Is there some way that I can use a jQuery UI dialog box instead of the alert box.

For example could I use a jQuery UI dialog box and have the responseText appear in a scrollable area on that?

Comment: Do you explicitly need the error information to display in some kind of pop-up dialog? I'd first suggest using `console.log(error_message);` in Chrome or Firebug for Firefox before popping up dialogs :)

Comment: Can you explain how I can send this data to the console log and how I can view it. I have been using fiddle to show HTTP error responses and just graduated to capturing this and putting in an alert log. I'm interested in other ways to display the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/qQdpP/

```
$("<div id='newdlg'></div>").html(ajaxContext.responseText)
.dialog({
 resizable: false,
 minWidth: 400,
 modal: true,
 title: 'Alert',
 hide: 'scale',
 buttons: {
   OK: function() {
       $(this).dialog( "close" );
     }
   },
   close: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).remove();
   } });​
```

Answer (score 1):

you can override the javascript alert function:

```
    function alert(message){
        $("#alert-context").text(message);
        $("#alert").dialog("open");
    }



<div id="alert" style="display: none">
    <img src="/xtras/images/yellow-warning.gif"/>
    <p id="alert-context">
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your success function put your response message in a dialog or in a [growl](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/). Example of a jQuery ui dialog:

```
//success handler of your ajax function
success: function(ajaxContext){  
   $('#dialog p').text(ajaxContext.responseText);
   $('#dialog').dialog("open");   
}
```

markup

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none">
    <p></p>
</div>
```